# Integrate a OAuth2 provider inside a SOA architecture - info needed

Tags: web-services, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, soa

I need to implement an authorization mechanism inside a SOA I'm currently designing.

We'll have three services, each one is imposed to only communicate using their public interfaces, so any kind of intercommunication and background processing must involve an authorization against other service endpoints.

Plus we'll have a client application running inside the user browser, which will, of course, need to access resources as well.

So we'll have both server-to-server and client-to-server communications (server-to-server will be needed when one of the services will need to perform some task involving resources exposed by another service).

I'm currently looking to implement OAuth2 since I'd really like to have a standard authorization framework, and more specifically I was thinking to implement the [Client Credentials](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-28#section-1.3.4) to authorize server-to-server, and [Resource Owner Password Credential](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-28#section-1.3.3) for the in-browser application (which will send the user data on login and then forget the password to enhance security).

It should be working well, but it seems I've found some parts of the specification conflicting with this design because:

- Client Credentials should only allow clients to access their own resource (so not acting on users resources)
- Each endpoint (3 in my case) should require a different token, while it would make more sense to me to have the browser client request one (and only one) token once and then use the same token agains all backend-services (using a refresh token whenever the current token expires, making all transparent to the final user, once the session -that will only exist inside the client application- expires it will delete the refresh token).
- The 2-legged oauth2 schema also seems a good way to handle the client-to-server communication but it seems to require additional permanent keys alongside user/password which doesn't seem to make sense to me (it would if I only have one client, but looking forward to create new clients it would not make sense to replicate user credentials to authenticate the user in order to get the private key).

So my questions are:

1. can I use a separated Authorization service exposing APIs to have one centralized OAuth2 provider?
2. can/should I share one token between the client and all backends?
3. given I'd exploit scopes to restrict the current clients abilities who should actually check at request-time the scope? Should it be the Authorization service or the Resource Server itself?
4. Any reccomendation of how would you implement a OAuth2 provider in this situation?

I'd really like to avoid a custom pub/key solution for service-to-service looking forward for possible 3rd party implementations (plus the dev team will be required to have a deep understanding of OAuth2 for other purposes so it would be really nice to use it internally as well).

P.S. I have no authentication service, the authentication of client and resource owner will be performed by the Authorization framework itself since it encapsulates user account. But I also have a Users service handling user preferences so it would also be possible to export the resource owner credentials verification there.